# Intermediate matrices in the positive definite ordering.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let  $$ M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   b & c \\
  \end{array} } \right],$$
be a positive definite matrix such that $M \succeq xI_d$, for some $x > 0$. Here '$\succeq$' means the usual order on positive definite matrix. Now, let $x'$ be a number such that $a>x'>x$. Can we find conditions on $x'$ such that
$$ 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   b & c \\
  \end{array} } \right] \succeq
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x' & 0 \\
   0 & x \\
  \end{array} } \right]?$$

Comment: Conditions like what? For example, $(x')^2 \le ac - b^2$ is a necessary [but probably not sufficient] condition. Like that?

Comment: In terms of $a$, $b$, __and__ $x$, it is possible to give a necessary and sufficient condition.